# Run curl inside php

Tags: php, api, curl, post

I want to execute `Curl` code inside `PHP`.

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.sightengine.com/1.0/check.json' \
     -F 'api_user=1********5' \
     -F 'api_secret=q**************Q' \
     -F 'media=@/full/path/to/image.jpg' \
     -F 'models=nudity'
```

Above code has four parameters to pass to the api. Below PHP code I tried to execute:

```
function image()
{
    $body_data = http_build_query(array('api_user' => 1********5,
                       'api_secret' => 'q**************Q',
                       'media' => $_FILES['image']['name'],
                       'models' => 'nudity'));

    // Configure cURL
    $image_curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($image_curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sightengine.com/1.0/check.json");
    curl_setopt($image_curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // Use POST
    curl_setopt($image_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_data); // Setup post body
    curl_setopt($image_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Receive server response

    // Execute request and read responce
    $session_response = curl_exec($image_curl);
    $response = json_decode($session_response);

    print_r($response);
}
```

**Response:**

> stdClass Object ( [status] => failure [request] => stdClass Object ( [id] => req_2365jHPuLcC6Bydh7WNd7 [timestamp] => 1512542730.57 [operations] => 0 ) [error] => stdClass Object ( [type] => argument_error [code] => 4 [message] => No media specified ) )

Now the problem is fro the `media` and `models` parameters.

1. I'm not sure the file path to `media` parameter has some problem. And do I want to and an additional `@` in-front of the path.
2. I'm I defined all parameters in `$body_data` array and passing them to the `CURLOPT_URL` properly.

Please help me to solve this issue. When I try this in `POSTMAN` it works fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/Sightengine/client-php - without Guzzle 79 lines of code..

Comment: Can I use this for an uploading image? Means before it get upload to server.

Comment: Do I only need to install this client-php in my working project. I'm not getting it actually. Please help me to do this please. And Im using codeigniter framework for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `http_build_query`.

PHP 5.5, 5.6 etc supported to pass `@` sign, but deprecated in PHP 7. Now we can use https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php .

```
$body_data = array(
    'api_user' => '3454',
    'api_secret' => 'q**************Q',
    'models' => 'nudity'
);

$body_data['media'] = new CurlFile(realpath('file.jpg'));

// Configure cURL
$image_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($image_curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sightengine.com/1.0/check.json");
curl_setopt($image_curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // Use POST
curl_setopt($image_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_data); // Setup post body
curl_setopt($image_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Receive server response

// Execute request and read responce
$session_response = curl_exec($image_curl);
$response = json_decode($session_response);
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong on above `image()` function that I'm using? Curl execution works fine for some other api calls. But fails when I try to give an upload image path.

Comment: You are using `$_FILES['image']['name']` which is name of the file. You should use the location where the file exists which is $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] . You should append `@` in front of the path, so it will be as ` 'media' => @ . $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` . Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried like this `'media=' => '@/'.$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` but still the same error.

Comment: Can you tell me why you have added a `/` after `@` ? Please try using a real file than uploaded file. Post the error also.

Comment: Without the `/` also its not working. I updated the response too.

Comment: I have updated code to make use of CurlFile. So it should work on all php versions. For the record there was a flag called `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` which used `@` sign for files to be uploaded. Details over http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php